# All transactions are not displayed in HTML report with JAnalyser in browser

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, janalyser

I am using JAnalyser for JMeter results analysis. After clicking "Show Analysis" icon, an HTML report was opened on browser. When I observed "Transaction Response Time Summary - Overview" all transactions were not shown on the page.

I had 144 transactions but I saw only 15 transactions. How can I see all the transactions in the list?

Note: In my JMeter Test plan, there were 5 Thread groups.

Answer (score 1):

The following 2 ways would work for displaying all transactions in browser:

1. An issue with screen resolution: Use zoom out in  your browser  (zoom in/out). You should able to see a small icons at the end which you can navigate to the transactions.
2. Another option is to click on "Transaction Summary (Filtered)" without applying filters. You should see exactly the same summary report what you see in Summary page.